# Edit hover in rallygrid missing

Tags: rally

Trying to do some cell validation in a rallygrid, but in order to add it I need to use objects in columnCfg instead of just file names.  I have something like

```
{
     dataIndex: 'field1',
     text: 'field1',
     editor: { xtype: 'rallynumberfield', allowBlank: true , allowDecimals: false},
     editable: true,
},
```

Everything works (and I'll add a renderer when it does) but I don't get the little edit hover (pencil icon) on this column.  Any hint where to look? My goal is for it to look like a default grid with just the renderer, but as soon as I use the options opbject instead of a string, the hover goes away. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this - I'm seeing the same issue (i.e. cells in column are editable, but the "pencil hover is missing). This looks like an oversight in the rendering of the component in AppSDK2. I'll file a Defect with Rally Engineering. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks.  As a workaround I can probably add my own style with overCls  and copy the default style. I'll try when I have time.